# Multivariate seasonal time series in dlm in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to build a dynamic linear model (dlm) in R for my bivariate seasonal (monthly) time series. I found the following resources that helped me model bivariate cases, but there is no seasonality component included (with my understanding):

*Tutorial: State-Space Modelling*
https://kevinkotze.github.io/ts-4-tut/ (see Section 9, "Multivariate state-space models")

*Package 'dlm'* description file
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf (see example on page 17)

I am so please if you can help me to write the function with seasonality in dlm modeling.

Here is the code I used:

```r
library(dlm)
data(NelPlo)

# 1. Build the model 

buildSu <- function(x) {
    Vsd <- exp(x[1:2])
    Vcorr <- tanh(x[3])
    V <- Vsd %o% Vsd
    V[1,2] <- V[2,1] <- V[1,2] * Vcorr
    Wsd <- exp(x[4:5])
    Wcorr <- tanh(x[6])
    W <- Wsd %o% Wsd
    W[1,2] <- W[2,1] <- W[1,2] * Wcorr
    return(list(
        m0 = rep(0,2),
        C0 = 1e7 * diag(2),
        FF = diag(2),
        GG = diag(2),
        V = V,
        W = W))
}

# 2. MLE parameter estimation
suMLE <- dlmMLE(NelPlo[,1:2], rep(0,6), buildSu); suMLE

buildSu(suMLE$par)[c("V","W")]

StructTS(NelPlo[,1], type="level") ## compare with W[1,1] and V[1,1]

StructTS(NelPlo[,2], type="level") ## compare with W[2,2] and V[2,2]

model.fit <- buildSu(suMLE$par)
model.filtered <- dlmFilter(NelPlo[,1:2], model.fit)

# 3. forecasting 
y1 <- dlmForecast(model.filtered, nAhead=12,sampleNew=1)
```

I am so please if you can help me to write the model with seasonality in dlm modeling and any valuable R examples are welcome.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data to work with and clarify how is your code not working for you. Where are you encountering the problem?

Comment: The dlm package has a DLM function for seasonal factors, `dlmModSeas()` (see page 21 in the package description file). If you search through the package for key word "season", you'll also find that you can add DLM's together, like `dlmModPoly() + dlmModSeas(4) # linear trend plus quarterly seasonal component` (page 8). Does that help you in any way?

Comment: Dear Sir/madam  #LC-datascientist  The code is a working code and running perfectly but i am not sure it is handling the seasonality (Because my time series with seasonality ). I need help for include seasonality component when i am building the model (Part 1 of the code ). dlmModPoly() + dlmModSeas(4) works for univariate (i tried ) but i don't know how to model multivariate using those two, please let me know if you know or any examples are welcome

Comment: Is `NelPlo` something that you expect us to be able to find in an available package? If not then this question should be closed as too vague. If it is then a better description of how to load it needs to be added.

Comment: Sir IRTFM, I edited the code NelPlo is the dataset in the package (Loading the package is enough ). If you google NelPlo data  It has multiple time series i used only two of them  for bivariate